# Don't resize child div when parent div changes size

Tags: css, html, resize

Consider the following markup

```
<div id="container"><div id="child"></div></div>
```

**I need the `#child` not to change it's width when the `#container` is being resized** (for example, when resizing browser window). How can this be done using css **without fixing the child's width?**

Also, is it possible to allow decrease in child's width but forbid increase?

Comment: first of all change your </div to </div>. you also need to show us the CSS you have right now.

Comment: In CSS alone? No. You'll have to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: This is a hypothetical question, so I can't provide any CSS.

Comment: We define the region within CSS by doing one of two methods, defining an explicit width and height, or protecting our elements using the box method with padding and margins. In the latter, if the parent container changes, the padding and margins will only retain the structure of the element from a scalable perspective. That would mean the only solution left is to declare an exact width value. Otherwise, #child needs #childHolder, with a position of relative, and a fixed width, then the child can use padding and margins so it doesn't need an explicit width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the child div's display: "inline" or "inline-block"

```
#child {
  display: inline-block;
}
​
```

Comment: But if it has any content, it will attempt to stretch it to fill the parent div after resize.